# Guzzle6 can't resolve external websites while in local environment

Tags: laravel, guzzle, guzzle6

I am having trouble using Guzzle with external websites when I'm in my local, development environment. I am able to use Guzzle without incident with other local sites on my machine.

### I am currently unable to use Guzzle with external websites in my local environment.

#### The Code

I have the following test route in my local Laravel application:

```
Route::get('guzzle', function() {
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->get("http://www.google.com");
dd($response);
});
```

#### The Response

When I execute this code from my local environment I receive the following error:

```
cURL error 6: Couldn't resolve host 'www.google.com' (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

---

### I am able to use Guzzle with local sites.

#### The Code

```
Route::get('guzzle', function() {
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->get("http://test.dev");
dd($response);
});
```

#### The Response

```
Response {#180 ▼
-reasonPhrase: "OK"
-statusCode: 200
-headers: array:7 [▶]
-headerLines: array:7 [▶]
-protocol: "1.1"
-stream: Stream {#171 ▶}
}
```

---

#### ...I need help.

I've looked at this for so long, I need some fresh ideas. Hopefully someone has an idea or a starting point.

This is the full error message that Laravel returns.

```
ConnectException in CurlFactory.php line 186:
cURL error 6: Couldn't resolve host 'www.google.com' (see   http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
in CurlFactory.php line 186
at CurlFactory::createRejection(object(EasyHandle), array('errno' => '6', 'error' => 'Couldn't resolve host 'www.google.com'', 'url' => 'http://www.google.com/', 'content_type' => null, 'http_code' => '0', 'header_size' => '0', 'request_size' => '0', 'filetime' => '-1', 'ssl_verify_result' => '0', 'redirect_count' => '0', 'total_time' => '0', 'namelookup_time' => '0', 'connect_time' => '0', 'pretransfer_time' => '0', 'size_upload' => '0', 'size_download' => '0', 'speed_download' => '0', 'speed_upload' => '0', 'download_content_length' => '-1', 'upload_content_length' => '-1', 'starttransfer_time' => '0', 'redirect_time' => '0', 'redirect_url' => '', 'primary_ip' => '', 'certinfo' => array(), 'primary_port' => '0', 'local_ip' => '', 'local_port' => '0')) in CurlFactory.php line 150
at CurlFactory::finishError(object(CurlMultiHandler), object(EasyHandle),     object(CurlFactory)) in CurlFactory.php line 103
at CurlFactory::finish(object(CurlMultiHandler), object(EasyHandle), object(CurlFactory)) in CurlMultiHandler.php line 180
at CurlMultiHandler->processMessages() in CurlMultiHandler.php line 108
at CurlMultiHandler->tick() in CurlMultiHandler.php line 123
at CurlMultiHandler->execute(true) in Promise.php line 240
at Promise->invokeWaitFn() in Promise.php line 217
at Promise->waitIfPending() in Promise.php line 261
at Promise->invokeWaitList() in Promise.php line 219
at Promise->waitIfPending() in Promise.php line 62
at Promise->wait() in Client.php line 129
at Client->request('get', 'http://www.google.com/', array()) in Client.php line 87
at Client->__call('get', array('http://www.google.com/', array(), array('proxy' => 'http://10.0.1.2'))) in routes.php line 29
at Client->get('http://www.google.com/', array(), array('proxy' => 'http://10.0.1.2')) in routes.php line 29
at RouteServiceProvider->{closure}()
at call_user_func_array(object(Closure), array()) in Route.php line 155
at Route->runCallable(object(Request)) in Route.php line 130
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 712
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 714
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 679
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 639
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 236
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 50
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 122
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 87
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Comment: I think you need to discuss what your local development is. Is it a virtual box? Does it have access to the outside world? ie from ssh can you ping an external domain?

Comment: Thanks @lee. I'm running apache 2.4 and php 5.6 on my mac (Snow Leopard). The machine does have access to the outside world. I can browse, ping, and curl google.com without any problems.

Comment: I take it you have install php5 curl? ie sudo apt-get install php5-curl

Comment: Yes, Curl is installed and enabled. I can "exec('curl http://www.google.com')" without any problems.

Comment: Have you also tried guzzle error response. ie
http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/psr7.html#responses

Comment: I have debugging turned in in my Laravel application. I get the following error on the page:

`cURL error 6: Couldn't resolve host 'www.google.com' (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)`

The full error dump is listed in my post above if that's helpful.

Comment: Googling this, it seems to be a DNS problem. Try googling to see if any answers help you.